Movie about an ex-convict who saves a man's life
I saw this 10+ years ago and my description will not be 100% accurate.
English language, released 1990-2005
The movie is about a man who just came out of prison to start a new life. He was sentenced for murder as a child when he killed a girl together with a friend. After being released from prison, he didn't tell anyone of his new friends what he did.
He then rescues a man in a car accident the media notices it and write something like "murderer saves persons life". His new friends and colleagues notices it, and they turn against him, which made him jump off a bridge.

This sounds very similar to one that has been asked recently, at least within the last few months. I'll check and see if I can find it...

The one that seems to be similar was this:  https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/69597/48050  ... could that be the same one?  If not, we'll keep looking.

It's not the one in the link. It was almost the same details and wording as the one above and there was no answers to it. May be it was closed and deleted.

Yes, @madmada, you are correct. It was asked (18 days ago, based on the external reference), but deleted. See this: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75044/whats-the-name-of-the-movie ... I found the external reference here: http://www.moviemag.pw/releases/whats-the-name-of-the-movie-1.c/?channel=

Thanks for the effort! And yes, I posted this previously without any luck. Thought I might give it one last try before giving up for good! It's not the one in the link above, but a very similar concept. However, my main character was proven guilty at the age of 10-14 and served his full sentence before being released.

Also, there was a flashback of the actual murder in the movie. A girl was provoking him in some way and he ended up killing her with a weapon. Could've been a knife.

Putting this forward as you say you are not 100 percent on details.
This plot sounds similar to Boy A with the notable differences being:
-Boy A movie was released around 2007
-The protagonist saves a girl from a car crash
Otherwise your description is remarkably similar to Boy A, starring Andrew Garfield as Boy A, who when young was part of a crime with a mate leading to the murder of a girl. Upon release from some kind of detention center Boy A is given a new identity and starts a new life, gets a job and meets a girl etc - basically builds a new life for himself.
A little later he happens to save a girl from a car crash which leads to a newspaper article and a little bit of fanfare. He is somehow “outed” through recognition of him from the car crash article as being part the murder of the girl in years past.
This leads to a downfall of his new life and he ends up ultimately at a kind of jetty. 
Boy A at IMDB

HUGE thank you for that! "Boy A" is the name of the movie! I almost started to believe that the movie didn't exist and was made up from a foggy dream I've had. THANK YOU!

No worries, you can close out the question as answered if you wanna help out the site.
